# Determine the current user's shell

Tags: shell

I'm programming a .sh script that will, at some point, change the shell of the user to /bin/zsh. The command is of course the following:

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

However this asks for the user's password, and I would like to only execute it if the current user's shell is not already `/bin/zsh`. For this I need a command that would let me know the current shell, and compare it with `"/bin/zsh"` or something alike. I found there's a c `getusershell` function, but isn't there a way to know this from a shell script?

**Update:** Sorry, I mean the shell that the user has specified as his preferred shell. So yes, the one specified in `/etc/passwd`. The logic behind this is that, the script is about to change the user's preferred shell to be zsh, and I just want the script to check first if it isn't already zsh.

Comment: grep /etc/passwd to to get the user's "official" shell. but note that they may NOT be actually running this script from that shell. they could very well login in using (say) dash, manually run bash, and have switched to korn shell, etc...

Comment: @MarcB If we're only supporting Linux, it's better to use `getent passwd "$USER"` than to grep `/etc/passwd`, since getent will search whahtever's configured in nsswitch (LDAP, NIS, etc), whereas grepping `/etc/passwd` only works on systems configured to _use_ `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: What do you mean by "current shell"? The one currently specified in `/etc/passwd` or the one currently being executed?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the shell that the user has specified as his preferred shell. So yes, the one specified in `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`$SHELL` returns the shell of the current user:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
```

Comment: Ok now I feel silly for not knowing about `$SHELL` before. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that `$SHELL` is only identical with the one in `/etc/passwd` if the user didn't start or exec a different shell. The bullet proof way to find the login shell is by looking in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: @Jens, not bullet proof. The user entry might be elsewhere than /etc/passwd like NIS, NIS+ or LDAP.

Comment: @jlliagre Fair enough. "Looking in `/etc/passwd`" would then be "ypmatch byname" :-)

Comment: @Jens: Not if your system doesn't have `ypmatch`, and `ypmatch` doesn't look at LDAP.

Comment: This is not true in general, and depends on the user's settings. Starting `zsh -f` with `SHELL` unset leaves it unset. And ksh93 sets `SHELL` to `/bin/sh` on startup if it is not already set!

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't assume `/etc/passwd` is the location where the user's shell is stored.

I would use this:

```
getent passwd $(id -un) | awk -F : '{print $NF}'
```

Edit: Note that getent is only implemented on Solaris, BSDs and GNU/Linux based OSes.

AIX, HP-UX and OS X have their own ways to do a similar thing (resp. `lsusers -c`, `pwget -n` and `dscl ...`) so this command should be enhanced should these OSes need to be supported.

Comment: Sadly, getent isn't POSIX, so you assume Solaris, any of the BSDs or Linux.

Comment: this actually was the only command that worked for command injection on a php web page.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F: '$1 == "myusername" {print $NF}' /etc/passwd
/bin/zsh
```

Or, if you have the username in shell variable `var`:

```
awk -F: -v u=$var '$1 == u {print $NF}' /etc/passwd
```

This assumes `/etc/passwd` is locally complete (as opposed to being NIS served; see your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and respective man page).

Comment: Wouldn't this just get the user's assigned shell? The question asks for the current one.

Comment: I think "current shell" refers to the one in `/etc/passwd`. It is meaningless to change any other shell to zsh with `chsh`. You can't replace a running shell. But yes, the question is ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my question was not clear enough. When I said "current shell" I meant the shell that the user has currently assigned as his preferred one, that is, the one I'm about to change over to be zsh.

Answer (score 1):

The following command will give you current shell (in the CMD cell):

```
ps -p $$
```

Comment: That's the currently executing shell, which may or may not be the user's login shell.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
ps p $$ | awk '{print $5}'
```

Sometimes $SHELL and values in /etc/passwd are incorrect.

Comment: That's the currently executing shell, which may or may not be the user's login shell. In what sense would the value in `/etc/passwd` be "incorrect" (assuming the information is actually served from the `/etc/passwd` file)?

Comment: If your default shell is bash and from bash you type `zsh`.  Your current shell is no longer the one shown in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: The OP has made it clear that the shell specifid in `/etc/passwd` (or equivalent) is what he's interested in.

Comment: I believe that part was added after my answer.  Maybe because of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -e '@pw = getpwuid $< ; print $pw[8], "\n"'
```

This assumes that Perl is installed, properly configured, and in your `$PATH`, which is a fairly safe bet on most modern Unix-like systems. (It's probably a safer bet than that `getent` is available, or that user information is actually stored in the `/etc/passwd` file, or that the value of `$SHELL` hasn't been changed.)

`$<` is the real UID of the current process. `getpwuid()` returns an array of values from `/etc/passwd` *or* whatever other mechanism the system uses (NIS, LDAP). Element 8 of that array is the user's login shell.

The above can be slightly shortened to:

```
perl -e 'print +(getpwuid $<)[8], "\n"'
```

or

```
perl -e 'print((getpwuid $<)[8], "\n")'
```

The reasons for the unary `+` operator or the extra parentheses are rather obscure.